# How To Change a TextBox Value Based On Another TextBox Change Event

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I need some help to update a textbox value based on another textbox values change event. I
need both textbox values to be the same. Here is the code i use. Use this code in change
event of first text box.

```
var formpanel = Ext.widget('Form');
var copy = formpanel.down('[name=billingCity]').getValue();

formpanel.down('[name=mailingCity]').setValue(copy);
```

Using an alert for display the second text box value,it shows the correct value. But in
the design part the value remains unchanged.

Pls help me.

Answer (score 0):

Ext.widget('Form') means "creating a new Form component", not "getting back the current Form". So I think it should be:

```
change: function() {
   var formpanel = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('Form')[0];
   var copy = formpanel.down('[name=billingCity]').getValue();
   formpanel.down('[name=mailingCity]').setValue(copy);
}
```